# Can we use Frechet inequalities to infer significance of collections of hypothesis tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, probability-inequalities

There are numerous issues that have been identified both in the theory and practice of $p$-values, including the arbitrariness of confidence levels, interpretation, and tail-risk in the metadistribution of $p$-values. Leaving these aside, another common problem is the [family-wise error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) of [multiple hypothesis tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). The following considers a different approach than the usual [controlling procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures).

The [Frechet inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities) allow us to put lower and upper bounds on conjunctions and (inclusive) disjunctions of events from only the single-event probabilities.

$$\max \left(0, \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_k) - (n-1) \right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left( \bigwedge_{k=1}^n A_k \right) \leq \min_k \left\{\mathbb{P}(A_k) \right\}$$

$$\max \left\{ \mathbb{P}(A_k) \right\} \leq \mathbb{P}\left( \bigvee_{k=1}^n A_k\right) \leq \min \left( 1, \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_k) \right)$$

Given that $p$-values are probabilities that null hypothesis distributions could generate values more extreme than a chosen confidence level, could the Frechet inequalities be employed in inferring that certain disjunctions of these events are significant in the sense of being lower than the desired confidence level?