# Is there a way to adjust FDR threshold using correlation across tests (aka, number of estimated independent tests, like in Bonferroni correction)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate, gwas

For Bonferroni correction, correlations can be used to inform correction of multiple testing using the spectral decomposition of matrices. For example, in GWAS, the threshold is established to be 5e-8 after this kind of correction (account to the correction across SNPs). I'm wondering if there is an equivalent method that could be applied to the FDR test (aka, BH correction).

Thank you!

Comment: I've been considering the use of Frechet inequalities in another [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/529511/can-we-use-frechet-inequalities-to-infer-significance-of-collections-of-hypothes).