# Multiple post-hoc tests after Multivariate GLM/MANCOVA

Tags: multivariate-analysis, post-hoc, manova, multivariate-regression, tukey-hsd-test

I have three groups, where I am doing a multivariate GLM/MANCOVA to test for multivariate differences between groups (6 DVs), adjusting for 2 covariates. I would like to do *post-hoc* tests to see which DV is contributing more to the difference, for which I hope univariate tests (univariate GLM/ANCOVA) would suffice.
I also would like to see pair-wise differences between groups, primarily to know if there's difference between groups 2 and 3. I have a relatively small sample size of *n* = 15 in each group. So I'm afraid a discriminant analysis wont be appropriate.
Can I do Tukey HSD for pairwise comparison between groups in each DV (although covariates won't be considered in Tukey), within each univariate *post-hoc* test? In that case, should I use a Bonferroni corrected alpha threshold (α/6) to correct for multiple Tukey HSD tests done for each of the 6 univariate test?
Or is it inappropriate to do multiple *post-hoc* tests like that?
Please pardon me if it is a stupid question (:-|)

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/529511/can-we-use-frechet-inequalities-to-infer-significance-of-collections-of-hypothes